# How to get installed application to be detected by rofi?

Tags: linux, i3, dmenu

I recently installed an IDE into /opt (I know that some recommend putting software into /usr/local but this was entirely self-contained) because the application was not available in my ditro's repositories and I had to install it from a .sh file.

The application runs fine when launching from the terminal; however, I would like to run it without having to declare the path to executable each time. I use Rofi as my application launcher but when I search for my IDE, it is not found(probably because I installed it without using a package manager - don't understand the reasons behind this behavior though).

How can I get this application that I installed to /opt to be searchable by an application launcher like Dmenu or Rofi?

Comment: For others: make sure the binary is an executable =)

Answer (score 4):

**1. $PATH**

> PATH is an environmental variable in Linux and other Unix-like
>   operating systems that tells the shell which directories to search for
>   executable files (i.e., ready-to-run programs) in response to commands
>   issued by a user.

Since I decided to install software into '/opt', I had to make sure that '/opt' was listed in PATH; it was not. I amended the '/etc/profile' file with

:/opt

at the end of the PATH variable. Note: editing '/etc/profile' will affect all users on the system, you should use the file in your home directory if you just want it changed for that specific user.

**2. Symlink**

> Symbolic links are like shortcuts or references to the actual file or
>   directory. Most of the time these links are transparent when working
>   with them through other programs... Symbolic links are used all the
>   time to link libraries and make sure files are in consistent places
>   without moving or copying the original.

Amending the $PATH variable only addressed part of the problem. Adding /opt to the $PATH variable only added that directory and not the specific application located inside. I also needed to create a symbolic link - or symlink - in the /opt directory to the specific application so it was searchable in my application launcher.

ln -s /opt/applicationFolder/executable /opt/applicationName

This creates a symlink for the the executable located in '/opt/applicationFolder' in the directory '/opt/' with the name 'applicationName'. Had to logout/restart to see changes.

Resources:

- [LINFO](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html)
- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux)
- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux)
- [Nixtutor](https://www.nixtutor.com/freebsd/understanding-symbolic-links/)

Comment: Why not just put a symlink into a directory that is already in `PATH`? For example `ln -s /opt/applicationFolder/executable /usr/local/bin/applicationName`. That way, you do not have to modify any configuration file (that may be overwritten when updating).

Comment: My problem is that `/opt` is in `PATH` when I do `echo $PATH`, but not when xmonad spawns my launcher. I've prefixed my launcher command with `echo $PATH >/tmp/path.log`, and it's not empty, but hasn't `/opt` in it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure rofi is installed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rofi
```

To get list of installed and running applications on rofi:

```
rofi -show combi -combi-modi "window,drun,ssh" -modi combi
```

Bind above command to a key for launching from key directly

To show application installed in non bin directory, add a desktop file your_app.desktop in ~/.local/share/applications

The your_app.desktop should contain following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/absolute_path/to/YourApp
Type=Application
Categories=Development
Name=name of the Your App, for example : Eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Run**

> Shows  a list of executables in $PATH and can launch them (optional in a terminal). Pressing the
> delete-entry binding (shift-delete) will remove this entry from the run  history.  Pressing  the
> accept-custom binding (control-enter or shift-enter) will run the command in a terminal.

2. **DRun**

> Same as the run launches, but the list is created from the installed desktop files. It automati‐
> cally launches them in a terminal if specified in the Desktop File.  Pressing  the  delete-entry
> binding  (shift-delete)  will remove this entry from the run history. Pressing the accept-custom
> binding (control-enter or shift-enter) with custom input (no entry matching) will run  the  com‐
> mand in a terminal.

If you want to run your IDE using `rofi -show drun`, you should add a .desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications` with the following content :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/opt/path/to/IDE
Type=Application
Categories=Development
Name=name of the IDE, for example : Qt Creator
```

More about desktop entry files: [developer.gnome.org](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/)