# How do I get Rofi/Dmenu to read my $PATH?

Tags: path, dmenu, rofi

I have a very similar issue to [How to get installed application to be detected by rofi?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364773/how-to-get-installed-application-to-be-detected-by-rofi) - or rather a followup question.

My question is, outside of symlinking, is there a way to export my path for Rofi or similar apps? It is already set in my .bashrc profile and .bashrc (my .profile source .bashrc).

Example, in this case, is most of my personal scripts and emacs is self live in `$HOME/local/bin`. Currently, Roli or Dmenu doesn't reflect `$HOME/local/bin` even though when I echo $PATH from my terminal it returns the correct path values.

I do sync most of the scripts to another machine that is shared so I would like to not resort to linking things out of my home directory if I don't have to.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? wondering the same thing

Comment: It ended up being an oversite on my part. My path wasn't being reloaded in my .profile or .bashrc. So I'd make a change and my the correct path wasn't loaded.